# Distributive "if" with numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have two arrays, `x` and `y`, and want an array whose element `i` is `x[i]` if `x[i] > y[i]`; otherwise, it is `y[i]`.

Is there some pre-written method in numpy to do this?

Comment: Are x and y the same shape?

Comment: I can make them so but I'd be interested in a general answer if there's one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just looking for "pointwise maximum of 2 arrays", which can be obtained with `numpy.maximum()`

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2])
y = np.array([1, 2, 0])
np.maximum(x, y)
```

outputs `array([1, 2, 2])`

Answer (score 2):

A general way to do this is to construct a truth table and then use that to select indices from `x` or `y`

eg.

```
a = np.random.rand(10)
b = np.random.rand(10)
truth_table = a > b
# where truth_table[i] is True, select a[i] else b[i]
new_arr = np.where(truth_table, a, b)
# in one step
new_arr = np.where(a > b, a, b)

assert ((a >= b) == (new_arr == a)).all()
assert ((a <= b) == (new_arr == b)).all()
```

`numpy.where` is more powerful than this, in that it can broadcast one or both of input arrays to the same shape as truth table. eg.

```
# where a[i] is greater than b[i], select a[i], else 0
new_arr = np.where(a > b, a, 0)
```